# What is this VTech Variety game in Abwärts (1984 movie)?

Tags: game-identification

In *Abwärts* (1984 movie), I see an old VTech Variety LCD game, where there is an ambulance:

[image: screenshot of the game described in the question]

I don't know the exact name of the game. Does anyone know the game name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Searching on the Internet, I found that the game name is *[Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Game_%26_Watch_games#Fire)*, a [Game & Watch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_%26_Watch) game by Nintendo.
*Fire* was not actually released for the VTech Variety. My source is the German-language [Wikipedia article for the movie.](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abw%C3%A4rts_(1984))

Comment: So if the game wasn't available on a "VTech", how did they do it in the movie? Was it some special one off version or some movie prop?

Comment: I own a "Fire" Game&Watch and can testify that the screen shown here is that game.  However the case is entirely different.  The Fire LCD is not a matrix display; it has the actual images for every game position etched into it, and the computer turns them on in various combinations.  Fire has lateral movement only and thus no need for the "+" controller or a fire button, which makes me believe the image shows a bespoke prop for the movie.  Maybe they couldn't get licensing from Nintendo, maybe they got Product Placement from Vtech, or maybe both.

Comment: The Wikipedia page also points out that the prop has the name of the film on it - the black writing with the upwards pointing arrow.